# Why did `git clean` delete more files than it should have?

Tags: git

Here's the output from some git commands I recently executed:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../../.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs

$ git clean -fd ../..
Removing ../../.yarn/releases/yarn-3.1.1.cjs
Removing ../lame/lame-3.100/ACM/
Removing ../lame/lame-3.100/Dll/
Removing ../lame/lame-3.100/debian/
...more lines...
```

According to `git status`, the only untracked file is `yarn-3.1.1.cjs`; so why did `git clean` delete some extra lame files too?

(I didn't lose anything important, just curious why git behaved this way.)

Comment: Another reminder that the `--dry-run` [option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#Documentation/git-clean.txt---dry-run) is a must before any real use of the `git clean` command... Glad that you didn't lose anything important.

Comment: According to `git status` the file `yarn-3.1.1.cjs` is the only one **with changes**. But it's not a list of all untracked files. Try `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` to list all untracked files.

Comment: @RomainValeri Why doesn't `git status` list all untracked files? Doesn't the `-u` argument default to `all`?

Comment: Were the lame files somehow excluded/ignored? That would explain why `git status` didn't show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happened was all the lame stuff `git clean` deleted was just empty directories. `git status` does not list empty untracked directories.